# Connection property has not been initialized error happened when calling ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, sql-server

The C# code:

```
SqlConnection c;

string str = "Data Source =(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DinoData.mdf;";
str += "Integrated Security= True";
c = new SqlConnection(str);

SqlCommand getxp = new SqlCommand("SELECT xp FROM [User] Where Username = @username");
getxp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", (string)Session["CurentUserid"]);

c.Open();
Session["xp"] = (int)getxp.ExecuteScalar();
c.Close();

if ((int)Session["xp"]<200)
{
    Response.Redirect("Must-Had.aspx", true);
}
```

The error:

> ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteScalar:
>   Connection property has not been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the connection to your `SqlCommand`. Like this:

```
SqlCommand getxp = new SqlCommand("SELECT xp FROM [User] Where Username = @username", c);
```

Or:

```
getxp.Connection = c;
```

Comment: @OzCohen your error was not to read the message. It says exactly this.