# Error connecting my SQL Server to a Winforms app

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is my code I want to connect my SQL Server to a Winforms app written in C#

```
private void HomePage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection Co = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NAHRO;Initial Catalog=gym;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    Co.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = "Select count(PlayerGender) from Player_table where gender='male'";

    Object temp = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    label4.Text = temp.ToString();
}
```

I get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: The error seems to be telling you the problem here. You don't define anywhere what connection the object `cmd` is using.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) it shows you what the problem is with examples of how you *should* be doing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447376/executescalar-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512923/connection-property-has-not-been-initialized-error-happened-when-calling-execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - you need to **assign** your connection the `SqlCommand` object - and best is to put everything in `using() { ... }` blocks:

```
private void HomePage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "Select count(PlayerGender) from Player_table where gender='male'";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NAHRO;Initial Catalog=gym;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        Object temp = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        label4.Text = temp.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, it WORKED!